# 'req' is declared but its value is never . Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: node.js, typescript

This my code

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 8080;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello, world.');
});
server.listen(port);
```

i get an error

> 'req' is declared but its value is never . Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type

I know three ways to fix a mistake.1 `// @ts-ignore`, 2 `(req:any, res:any)`, 3 `"noImplicitAny": false`.
I do not like all these ways.If a different approach to solve this problem ?.

Comment: Maybe from tslint? I'm pretty sure `noUnusedLocals` does not throw an error when the previous parameters are not used. And, iirc I had the same problem using tslint time ago

Comment: changing `req` to `_` might help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html

> Parameters declaration with names starting with _ are exempt from the unused parameter checking.

So to address the first error, use something like:

```
const server = http.createServer((_req, res) => {
```

or even

```
const server = http.createServer((_, res) => {
```

To address the second error, you will either have to explicitly annotate `req` as `any` or import the `IncomingMessage` type from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/http.d.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Set `noUnusedLocals` to `false` in your tsconfig to ignore unused variable errors for your whole code base. See [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options). Otherwise, use one of the other approaches you mentioned.